# How to get encoding error from compile(...)

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I use `exec open("tx.py")` in Python on a non-ASCII file, I get an error like this:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file tx.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

However, when I do `compile(open("tx.py").read(), "tx.py", "exec")` I get no such errors, and Python 2.7 happily compiles the file. How could I get this same `SyntaxError` from *compile(...)*?

Please note that my goal here is not to fix the `SyntaxError`, but to make *compile(...)* behave the same way as *exec* does.

Comment: do you have a invalid character in some comment or docstring?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry: In a string literal. But it shouldn't matter. The invalid character is there on purpose. Its purpose is to trigger the SyntaxError. How do I trigger the SyntaxError with *compile(...)*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the source code, using `exec` ends up with calling `PyTokenizer_FromFile`, while `PyTokenizer_FromString` is used for `compile()`. These differ in how the tokenizer is set up.

With `PyTokenizer_FromFile` the tokenizer starts with an empty buffer, and calls are made to the `fp_readl` function to fill the tokenizer buffer, and this can trigger the exception you've seen (if the tokenizer saw no encoding declaration and a non-ASCII character has been seen). File contents are then recoded to UTF8 and handled as such by the tokenizer, for ease of tokenizing. Tokens are later re-encoded to the original codec.

When using `PyTokenizer_FromString` then the buffer is set to the string passed in. The string is checked for a BOM and for a PEP 263-compliant comment, just as a file would be on reading, but if no such codec was set, the string is just handled as is by the tokenizer and no re-encoding takes place. The `encoding` field of the tokenizer is left empty in that case, just as it would be for an ASCII file. With the buffer initialized, and no fileobject, no calls to `fp_readl` are made and the exception is never raised.

Because of these differences, there is *no way* to force `compile()` to behave exactly like `exec`. You'll have to do the same tests manually:

- Check for a BOM in the first bytes; test against the `codecs.BOM_*` constants
- Check for the `coding` comment in the first two lines.
- If these are missing, try to decode from ASCII and throw the `SyntaxError` exception manually if the decode fails.

```
import codecs
import re
_boms = (codecs.BOM_UTF8,) + tuple(v for k, v in vars(codecs).iteritems() if k.startswith('BOM_') and k[-3:] in ('_LE', '_BE'))
_coding_line = re.compile('\s*#\s*coding[:=]\s*[-\w.]+').match

def compile_precheck(string):
    if string.startswith(_boms):
        return
    for line in string.splitlines()[:2]:
        if _coding_line(line)
            return
    try:
        string.decode('ascii')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        raise SyntaxError(
            "Non-ASCII character in source string but no encoding declared")

source = open("tx.py").read()
compile_precheck(source)
tx = compile(source, "tx.py", "exec")
```

Comment: I think you wanted to write `compile` instead of `custom_compile` in the last line.

Comment: @Vincent: indeed, I had not scrolled up far enough.

Answer (score 1):

With this line :

```
tx = compile(open("tx.py").read().decode('ascii'), "tx.py", "exec")
```

Or :

```
import codecs
tx = compile(codecs.open("tx.py", encoding='ascii').read(), "tx.py", "exec")
```

I got this error :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 18: ordinal not   in range(128)
```

This is the closer I can get to your SynthaxError.

EDIT: You can write your own custom compile and format the expected error as you will :

```
def custom_compile(source, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return compile(source.decode('ascii'), *args, **kwargs)
    except UnicodeDecodeError as error:
        raise SyntaxError(error)

tx = custom_compile(open("tx.py").read(), "tx.py", "exec")
```

Error :

```
SyntaxError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. My goal is to make *compile(...)* behave exactly like *exec*. Not only the SyntaxError, but everything else, including detection of byte-order marks (BOM) etc. The SyntaxError is just an indicator that they work the same way.